# Cookieless = Autodetect Web Services problem brings errors on call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cookieless

Having a Simple "Hello World" web service on a web application that has cookieless= AutoDetect. I cannot call the web service without an error. If the cookieless is set to False or True then everything is ok. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DoctorMick The Error ---> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

<html>....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is here http://dougrees.blogspot.com/2008/07/using-autodetect-cookieless-sessions.html Thanks to all above comments.

Answer (score 1):

The cookieless=AutoDetect feature works by sending redirects (302 or 403 IIRC) to the browser in order to detect whether cookies are supported.

It then plants the various required Id's in the URL rather than using cookies if the support isn't there.

Make sure the method you are testing the web service with supports these redirects and the checks they make for cookies.

If you're testing the web service in Visual Studio using the Add Web Reference option, then VS has known problems with the redirects which can muddy the waters.

In that case try modifying your reference to configure support for automatic cookie detection:

```
http://<host>/<app>/<webservice>.asmx?wsdl&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

Comment: This wont help me cause i m trying to use the service through Silverlight. And mainly i tried it also to win forms and still doesnt works

Comment: This is still the same cause (i.e. the code is attempting a perform a Response.Redirect), but good to see you got a solution in the end. Don't forget to flag the solution as Answered, even if you use your own answer :)